# Can i print multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in below format

```
(
[Albania] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Margaret Ramirez
                [date_of_birthday] => 24-Mar-1997
                [email] => mramirez1g@godaddy.com
                [department] => Engineering
            )

    )

[Argentina] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Samuel Fisher
                [date_of_birthday] => 16-Jan-1955
                [email] => sfisher1e@amazon.co.uk
                [department] => Sales
            )

    )

[Azerbaijan] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Jason Mccoy
                [date_of_birthday] => 11-Nov-2001
                [email] => jmccoy22@shop-pro.jp
                [department] => Research and Development
            )

    )
```

I want to get output from that array as below format
[image]

Can anyone please help me regarding this problem.
thanks

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... as you see we're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts and we'll help you find YOUR mistakes, but nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Community needs to know what you have tried so far. Any code ?

Comment: you've heard of foreach and <?php right?

Comment: It is very straight forward solution. Try something & post here so that someone will help

Comment: use foreach() @fern petal and SO is not for giving you everything without your effort, please show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to show some effort, you can't expect people to write code for you. You need to try something, that's how you learn. Copy and pasting code won't help you.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date of Birth</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Department</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($countries as $country) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $country['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $country['date_of_birthday']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $country['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $country['department']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php
    foreach ($country as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $index => $val) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$val['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$val['date_of_birthday']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$val['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$val['department']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: i ll not encourage your answer, this answer is about 1 min but no one gave this answer, do you know why ? only because all wanted to try by himself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach($country as $contryKey => $contryValue) {
   foreach($contryValue as $index => $objValue) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$objValue->name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$objValue->date_of_birthday."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$objValue->email."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$objValue->department."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}


?>
```